# ag-grid Display Subtotal row and a final Total row

Tags: ag-grid

[image]

The grid above displays Subtotal and Total. It is populated with data from the API, so we are not calculating anything. We want to calculate the Subtotal and Total from the grid so that sorting via product name works correctly.  The total we can put in the footer of the grid so that it is not sortable, but what is the best way to handle a Subtotal within the data?

Thanks

Comment: check pinned row or aligned grids in ag-grid documentation that will be something to look at for displaying total rows.